# D3D Shared surface not working in windows 7

Tags: wpf, direct3d, surface

I'm a newbie to Direct3D technology. And was trying out D3D shared surface code found at [Direct3D10, 11 and D2D in WPF - Round 2 DEMO!](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/wpf-disciples/jD7nDmMhTR4) by Jeremiah morrill Interop.D3DImage.rename2zp. I was able to compile the code without any issues but when I run it I see a blank screen [Output window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6ecw.png)

I'm using VS2013, DirectX SDK(June 2010) and windows 7 OS.

Answer (score 0):

D3D is often pretty good at telling you what the problem is.  If you go into the project properties, and enable native debugging, you might see messages in the output window which which will give you a clue - as long as you're running the debug version of the app of course.

There are many reasons it might be failing though - it could be that your graphics card doesn't support what the demo is doing, or that it's starting up with the wrong device settings.

Comment: I did run the program in debug mode after enabling native debugging. after going thru' the debug output i found the line ["The thread 0x18f8 has exited with code 0 (0x0)."] at the end. And i didn't find any other errors.

Comment: You will need to pass the debug flag to D3D, if you didn't already.  Otherwise you won't see the errors from the runtime.  Look at the device creation for a place to supply the flags...

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476107%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG